# Find a UNIT vector which is orthogonal to every vector in the range of f.

Tags: linear-algebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f1ggs.png)

How exactly do I find a unit vector? I know that orthogonal is when a vector dot a vector is equal to 0.

Comment: At least show the expression that you get for the orthogonal vector.

Comment: Better to type out the question here than to refer us to a picture somewhere else. There is help for formatting mathematics available via the Help menu. Anyway, if you have a vector, and you want a unit vector, you just divide your vector by its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be orthogonal to $$<p+q, q,p>$$ you may consider $$<1,-1,-1>$$

Normalize to get $$u= <\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}, -\frac {1}{\sqrt 3},-\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}>$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a vector $\textbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$ is orthogonal to some vector $\textbf{u} \in \text{rng}(f)$. Then $\textbf{u}$ is of the form $\textbf{u}=\begin{pmatrix}p+q\\q\\p\end{pmatrix}$, and since $\textbf{u}\bullet\textbf{v}=0$, then $$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\bullet \begin{pmatrix}p+q\\q\\p\end{pmatrix}=a(p+q) +bq+cp=(a+c)p+(a+b)q=0$$
So then $a+c=0$ and $a+b=0$. Thus, we choose any values of $a,b,c$ such that $a=-c=-b$. Consider for example, the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. This vector is orthogonal to $\textbf{v}$ and thus so is the unit vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$